# Cookie-challenges, storing logged in user

Tags: security, cookies, encryption

Hello fellow developers

I have obviously under estimated a thing when developing my first complex web site, where user creation and login is required.

It appears that cookies can be edited and modified by the user logged in, by using some developer tools i.e. in Google Chrome. That, I never gave a thought.

So, here is my issue.

1. When the user is logged in, I store the user name in a cookie.
2. If username-cookie is not blank, and I can find a user file with that name, the user is logged in, per se. Otherwise, no user is logged in.
3. When the user logs out, I simply expires the cookie, which works fine.

Now, the problem is, that a user obviously can edit the content of a cookie, outside the web application, or with javascript.

What would be the correct approach here to ensure, that the username cookie is not compromised in any way, other by my web application?

Making them read-only is not possible, I assume. Encrypting the cookie and then decrypting might work, I guess. Then, the cookie would be nonsense to the user, and if modified, result in a logout, as no valid username can be found upon decrypting the edited cookie.

I have stalked Googles cookies, and it appears that there are a lot of xxID cookies, which contains garbage. Does that mean, that encrypting/decrypting is the only way to make it work? I also considered some kind of login-ticket, but that would require a table lookup every time a user interacts with my web page.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what would be the correct approach?

Thanks in advance
Best regards,
Karsten Heitmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up **session management** for the language you are using.

The traditional approach is that when a user logs on, your application generates a long, cryptographically random token called the "session id" and sets that into a cookie. It stores data like who is logged in on the server side identified by the random value, so when a logged on user comes back, the browser sends the cookie with the random session id and the application can look up session data on the server side. This way an attacker has no way to guess a valid session id for a logged on user, assuming the session id is cryptographically random and long enough (which more precisely means it has enough entropy). Logging out means deleting the session data on the server side, and also removing the cookie, but that is not the most important part - the session will be invalid anyway.

Note that you should not code this yourself. You did not mention the language and environment you are developing in, but session management is rather tricky business if you want to secure it, and it is already provided by most languages / frameworks.

Just for curiosity, the encryption approach you mention is by the way a valid one. Some frameworks actually do that, but you should not attempt to code that either, because it is very easy to get it wrong, lots of things need to be taken care of to make it secure enough. Unfortunately an answer here is not the right format to go into details I'm afraid.

Btw you mention looking at Google. They use their own single sign-on solution, it is very complex compared to simple session management, so it's probably not the best example for you to look at. Find simple websites, most of those work the traditional way.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should try to maintain some kind of temporary server file, for every user session. A user file is created upon login, and deleted when the  user logs out.  That particular token should be a random token of some kind, stored as a cookie client side.  If someone tries to edit the contents of the cookie, it will point to nowhere, and hence the session  is hereby invalid. Yes. I suppose that would do the trick.

Comment: Oh, bugger. Did not complete my entry, sorry.

Comment: AAARGH.... I am new to this site, sorry :-) It appears that enter key = add comment.  Anyways... I will try to implement that idea momentarily. Sessions never occured to me. Thank you very much for that idea. Best regards, Karsten

Comment: You are welcome. :) Note that while it may be interesting to implement this to learn, it is tricky to make it secure. Your environment most probably already has this facility, you just have to use it.

Comment: The final implementation:

1. Create a GUID
2. Create a local session file with the same name as the GUID
3. Send the GUID as a cookie.
4. The client file contains the actual userid
5. If the cookie is deleted/modified: Session invalid, as no local session file matches the edited GUID, and thus the user is logged out.
I know my security relies on the in-built strength of the GUID uniqueness, but  the chance of two GUID's colliding is rather small, as I understand. Best regards, Karsten. PS: I code in Delphi 7, and its way too old-school, I know, but, old habbits .... :-)